# Proof of a theorem expressing every prime number as a linear combination with $\pm 1$ coefficients of the previous prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I saw an interesting theorem:

Let $p(k)$ is the $k$th prime number and define $p(0) = 1$. For $n\geq 1$, it is known that appropriate coefficients, $e(k) = \pm 1$, exist and satisfies the following equation:
$$p(2n) = p(2n-1) + e(0)p(0) + e(1)p(1) + \ldots + e(2n-2)p(2n-2), \\
p(2n+1) = 2p(2n) + e(0)p(0) + e(1)p(1) + \ldots + e(2n-1)p(2n-1).$$

Does anyone know the proof of this?

Comment: I didn't know this theorem. You ask for a proof, but can you give a reference of a site where you have **seen** it ? Besides, can you give explicitly what the e(k) are for $n=10$ for example ?

Comment: It is on a book "Elementary Number Theory", and e(k) is either 1 or -1. Thank you for first comment.

Comment: @JeanMarie Here are the examples until $n\le 13 : \\2 = 2*1\\
3 = 1*2 + 1\\
5 = 2*3 - 2 + 1\\
7 = 1*5 + 3 - 2 + 1\\
11 = 2*7 - 5 + 3 - 2 + 1\\
13 = 1*11 + 7 - 5 + 3 - 2 - 1\\
17 = 2*13 - 11 + 7 - 5 + 3 - 2 - 1\\
19 = 1*17 + 13 - 11 + 7 - 5 - 3 + 2 - 1\\
23 = 2*19 + 17 - 13 - 11 - 7 + 5 - 3 - 2 - 1\\
29 = 1*23 + 19 + 17 - 13 - 11 - 7 + 5 - 3 - 2 + 1\\
31 = 2*29 + 23 - 19 - 17 + 13 - 11 - 7 - 5 - 3 - 2 + 1\\
37 = 1*31 + 29 + 23 - 19 - 17 + 13 - 11 - 7 - 5 + 3 - 2 - 1\\
41 = 2*37 + 31 + 29 - 23 - 19 - 17 - 13 - 11 - 7 - 5 + 3 - 2 + 1$

Comment: It is Elementary Number Theory, David M. Burton

Comment: It is exercise 16 page 58 of this book "Elementary Number Theory" by David Burton. The property is indeed given in the way you gave it. "It is known that..." without proof.

Comment: @JeanMarie Note that a proof of this can be obtained by first setting all $e_i = -1$. Next, use that $1$ and the prime numbers form a [complete sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_sequence#Other_complete_sequences) to show that any appropriate required value can represented as a sum of $1$ and the prime numbers (using each value at most once), then add double this value to get all $e_i$ to be $-1$ or $1$.

Comment: @John Omelian Thank you very much. You should give this remark as an answer.

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much too!

Comment: @JeanMarie You're welcome. First, on paper, I used $e_i$ instead of $e(k)$ as in the question, then forgot to change this in my comment. Regarding posting an answer, note the question currently has one close vote, and contains little context, so I'm concerned that it doesn't meet the required quality standards, with the enforcement explained in [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/602049).

Comment: @John Omelian I understand. I am reluctant as well in such cases. But here the asker has shown involvement when you see his/her answers...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for explaining your reluctance as well, but if you believe that the OP has shown sufficient involvement, then feel free to post an answer yourself if you wish. Also, one minor point is that my surname is spelled "Omielan", not "Omelian".

Comment: I thought you were talking about the structure of this site, but I actually didn't know much because I started this site for the first time today. There seems to be a distinct difference from the writings, so I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: @puremath You just need to add some info regarding your attempt to solve this. Perhaps say something relevant about complete sequences, binary numbers, and [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate). ;)

Comment: Kind of related: representing integers using Fibonacci numbers: https://r-knott.surrey.ac.uk/Fibonacci/fibrep.html

Comment: @PM2Ring Wow, Thank you for information! And last question, how do I translate this article into a resolution state?

Comment: [Sequence maker using a greedy algorithm in Sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdkN2KgzAQhe8F3-HQZUGpUvRmQSrsI_S-SAndcQlsYswP7ON3Yq0_DeRizjkz8yUfuFipCI7GQPpOsGQsOdJeeDnoNEmTb6k9WXH3afJDPUzM3zifmbb6yps0AR_ZQw8e0t0mPzMvIx6DFpr-_eI9La60zw7sHgpE8SVz_Fp1OM67rNC_a9fIrrHXsuqetYs1Z11QmbFzSMQRY7ewOXyi3hA5HFuMay1ivTQo7nY4nVCjnOaKHbEooBbafrAIkHpiqpuGuTZ7eHXAuYXaaOugkO9VhbJFWDX6c_TWGBitDO_gYQb3EXzDK5wj66PMf1Qg4-t3T2FB5A-HaHlu&lang=sage)

Comment: @puremath Welcome to Math SE. Re: how to "... translate this article into a resolution state", if I understand correctly, you should first edit your question to include details of where the problem came from, such as in [Jean Marie's comment](/questions/4541500/proof-of-a-theorem-expressing-every-prime-number-as-a-linear-combination-with#comment9549030_4541500), plus what you've tried (e.g., with smaller $p(k)$, checked parity, etc.) and possibly other details such in PM 2Ring's comment. Then write an answer, with an upvote or you accepting it later marking your question as being "answered".